# jquery datepicker exclude all days except Tuesday and Friday, and exclude selected dates in conjunction

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I've tried for hours with no luck.  I need to first exclude all days except tuesday and friday.  Then there's an array of certain Tuesdays and Fridays I need to disable.  Alone each function works perfectly but for the life of me they will not work together?

working exclude all days except Tuesday and Friday:

```
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker(
        { beforeShowDay: function(day) {
            var day = day.getDay();
            var taken = ["2020-03-17"];
            var isTaken = '2020-03-17';

            if (day == 0 || day == 1 || day == 3 || day == 4 || day == 6)  {
                return [false]
            } else {
                return [true];
            }
         }
        });

});
```

Working exclude selected dates:

```
var array = ["03/17/2020","03/18/2020","03/19/2020"];

$(function(){

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
   });
});
```

How can I get these to work both at the same time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost all the way there, you just have to combine your conditions.  [Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/gvdwmk1t/).

I made some other minor changes:

- replaced `jQuery` with `$` for consistency;
- renamed some variables for clarity (eg it is a `date` passed to `beforeShowDay`, not a `day`, `array` doesn't remind us what it is or what we need to do with it).  It is easy to get things mixed up if you have 3 or 4 variables and all of them are dates or date-related;
- Inverted your day of week test.  Instead of testing which day to disallow, it is simpler to think of days allowed, especially when there are less of them;

Here's the code:

```
$(function(){

    var day, formatted,
        disallowed = ["03/17/2020","03/18/2020","03/19/2020"];

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            day = date.getDay();            
            formatted = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);

            // If it is a Tue or a Fri, AND it is not in the disallowed list, 
            // it should be selectable
            if ((day == 2 || day == 5) && disallowed.indexOf(formatted) === -1) {
                return [true];
            } else {
                return [false];
            }
        }
    })
});
```